# Using named parameters in Informix queries in an ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, informix

I'm trying to convert my queries to being parameterized, but am having issues with figuring out the syntax. This is error-free according to VS2012, but in runtime I get an error because the value of the parameter isn't being substituted into the query.

Here is the example code:

```
IfxCommand query = new IfxCommand("SELECT slm_slmno FROM slmmas WHERE 
    slm_logon = @Logon");
query.Parameters.Add("@Logon", logon);
```

Here is the error that the query returns when run:

```
Error Message = ERROR [42000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]A syntax 
    error has occurred.
Sql Query = SELECT slm_slmno FROM slmmas WHERE slm_logon = @Logon
```

It's clear from the error that the value of logon is not being substituted into the command. I'm using Informix 10.0. I've looked at the documentation (located at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/dqx1db2commandclass.htm ) but there are no clear examples that show the simple usage I'm trying to achieve. Any suggestions on how I need to better approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Vijay's solution worked, when dealing with multiple parameters it was an approach that would become rather verbose. I was able to modify the approach like such, which is much more minimal and will be easier to add multiple parameters with:

```
IfxCommand query = new IfxCommand("SELECT slm_slmno FROM slmmas WHERE 
    slm_logon = ?");
query.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter("Logon", logon));
```

Hopefully somebody else will find this useful.

Answer (score 6):

As per the example given at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.netpr.doc%2Fids_net_115.htm you can rewrite your query as below:

```
IfxCommand query = new IfxCommand("SELECT slm_slmno FROM slmmas WHERE 
    slm_logon = ?");
IfxParameter ifxp1 = new IfxParameter("Logon",DbType.String);
query.Parameters.Add(ifxp1);
ifxp1.Value = "your value";
```

Comment: This did work, so I marked it as helpful, but I was able to write a much shorter approach, which I've posted as an additional answer. I'll mark mine as the answer to the question in order to highlight it better for other users, but thank you for this approach as it did give me a working model to experiment with, and is what lead to the version I posted.

Answer (score -2):

If you are firing SQL queries, an alternative approach would be to have the parameter substitution done in C# strings itself, and pass on the final SQL to your command.

An example would be -

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT slm_slmno FROM slmmas WHERE slm_logon = {0}", logon);
IfxCommand query = new IfxCommand(sql);
```

Stored procs are a different case, and you would need to look at the informix adapter documentation.

Comment: using `String.Format` for supplying parameters is definitely going to cause sql injection attacks.

Comment: String.Format is how the code is written now, and injection attacks (and escaping) is why I'm rewriting it. :)